# AngularJS + ArcGIS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dojo, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am trying to use [ArcGIS JavaScript API](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/) inside an Angular application. As I see, it uses Dojo. So, I am trying to initialize ArcGIS from Angular directive like this:

```
  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    dojo.require('esri.map');
    var init = function () {
      console.log('dojo is ready');
      var map = new esri.Map("map-container", {
        center: [-111.3797, 56.7266 ],
        zoom: 16,
        basemap: "streets"
      });
      map.enableScrollWheelZoom()

    };
    dojo.addOnLoad(init);
  }
```

Looks like this way is not 100% correct because when I try to zoom by scrolling mouse wheel,  I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of null
```

My question, is how to properly to inject ArcGIS functionality inside an Angular app?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think a very 'AngularJS' style approach to this would be something like the following. (fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/technicolorenvy/2Ke62/4/)

I like using `angular-ui-router`, but this approach would also work w/ Angular's `$routeProvider`. The magic here is in the resolve object which will optionally 'wait' until a promise is resolved before continuing.

```
angular.module('webApp', ['ui.router'])
    // module (app) config
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/map');

        $stateProvider.state('map', {
            url: '/map',
            template: '<div id="map"></div>',
            controller: 'MapCtrl',
            resolve: {
                promiseObj: function ($q, $rootScope, wish) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer(),
                        deps = {
                            Map: 'esri/map',
                            FeatureLayer: 'esri/layers/FeatureLayer',
                            InfoTemplate: 'esri/InfoTemplate',
                            SimpleFillSymbol: 'esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol',
                            SimpleRenderer: 'esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer',
                            SimpleMarkerSymbol: 'esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol',
                            ScaleDependentRenderer: 'esri/renderers/ScaleDependentRenderer',
                            Color: 'dojo/_base/Color'
                        };

                    wish.loadDependencies(deps, function () {
                        deferred.resolve();
                        if (!$rootScope.$$phase) {
                            $rootScope.$apply();
                        }
                    });

                    return deferred.promise;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

As you can see above, we have a `map` state that has a `resolve` prop. You can then build an object that represents your ArcGIS/Dojo dependencies and pass that on to your `wish.loadDependencies` (see below).

Using `q` we will return a promise that gets resolved once all the dependencies are loaded via dojo's `require`

```
angular.module('webApp')
     // service that deals w/ our dojo require
    .service('wish', function () {

        // it's not require... it's a wish?
        var wish = {};

        function _loadDependencies(deps, next) {
            var reqArr = _.values(deps),
                keysArr = _.keys(deps);

            // use the dojo require (required by arcgis + dojo) && save refs
            // to required obs
            require(reqArr, function () {
                var args = arguments;

                _.each(keysArr, function (name, idx) {
                    wish[name] = args[idx];
                });

                next();
            });
        }

        return {
            loadDependencies: function (deps, next) {
                _loadDependencies(deps, next);
            },

            get: function () {
                return wish;
            }
        };
    });
```

after that, in your `MapCtrl`, you can call all the ArcGIS/Dojo fns directly (as you would normally), by the keys you used in the `deps` object that was constructed during app config, as they are now attached to the object returned by `wish.get()`.

What follows is a modified version of the example found here (https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/renderer_proportional_scale_dependent.html)

```
angular.module('webApp')
    // our map controller
    .controller('MapCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, wish) {

        var w = wish.get(),
            greenFill = new w.Color([133, 197, 133, 0.75]),
            greenOutline = new w.Color([133, 197, 133, 0.25]),
            layer,
            markerSym,
            renderer1,
            renderer2,

            CROPS_URL = 'http://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/arcgis/rest/services/USA_County_Crops_2007/FeatureServer/0';

        $scope.map = new w.Map('map', {
            center: [-98.579, 39.828],
            zoom: 4,
            basemap: 'gray'
        });

        layer = new w.FeatureLayer(CROPS_URL, {
            outFields: ['STATE', 'COUNTY', 'M086_07', 'AREA'],
            infoTemplate: new w.InfoTemplate('${COUNTY}, ${STATE}', '<div style="font: 18px Segoe UI">The percentage of the area of the county that represents farmland is <b>${M086_07}%</b>.</div>')
        });
        layer.setDefinitionExpression('AREA>0.01 and M086_07>0');


        markerSym = new w.SimpleMarkerSymbol();
        markerSym.setColor(greenFill);
        markerSym.setOutline(markerSym.outline.setColor(greenOutline));
        renderer1 = new w.SimpleRenderer(markerSym);
        renderer1.setProportionalSymbolInfo({
            field: 'M086_07',
            minSize: 1,
            maxSize: 10,
            minDataValue: 0,
            maxDataValue: 100
        });

        //for the second renderer increase the dot sizes and set a backgroundFillSymbol
        renderer2 = new w.SimpleRenderer(markerSym);
        renderer2.setProportionalSymbolInfo({
            field: 'M086_07',
            minSize: 5,
            maxSize: 15,
            minDataValue: 0,
            maxDataValue: 100
        });

        layer.setRenderer(new w.ScaleDependentRenderer({
            rendererInfos: [{
                'renderer': renderer1,
                    'minScale': 50000000,
                    'maxScale': 10000000
            }, {
                'renderer': renderer2,
                    'minScale': 0,
                    'maxScale': 5000000
            }]
        }));

        $scope.map.addLayer(layer);
    });
```

working fiddle demonstrating the above code, found here http://jsfiddle.net/technicolorenvy/2Ke62/4/

Comment: I like your solution, but I have a small problem.
I am using angular translate and it takes a split second to load init.js from "//js.arcgis.com/3.14" causing angular translate to show up as {{'something'|translate}} instead of the rendered text until init.js loads in order to load 'require'.
Do you know of a way remove the require dependency inside the wish service ?

Comment: I'd handle this in your UI via preloader or 'data loaded' flags. a pretty decent explanation of the problem and possible solution here http://www.code-hound.com/add-a-preloader-to-your-website-using-angularjs/

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you are trying to build your map inside a directive element. That's a legitimate use, but I would make sure that you utilize the AMD loader of Dojo to load your modules and then [bootstrap](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) your Angular app after all the Dojo goodness is ready.

I recently put together a write-up on Angular/Esri dev, and the source code for a sample project can be found [here](https://github.com/odoe/angular-esri).

What I actually do is build the map from a Controller, but the process should be similar to building it in the directive.

```
define([
    'angular',
    'esri/map'
], function(angular, Map) {
    function mapConfigs() {
        return {
            basemap: 'streets',
            center: [-118.1704035141802,34.03597014510993],
            zoom: 15
        };
    }
    function mapGen(elem) {
        return new Map(elem, mapConfigs());
    }
    function AppController($scope) {
        $scope.map = mapGen('map');
    }
    function init(App) {
        App.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', AppController]);
        return AppController;
    }
    return { start: init };
});
```

I use a bootstrap module to build all my Angular bits using the Esri/Dojo bits before bootstrapping the Angular application.

```
define([
    'angular',
    'controllers/AppController',
    'widgets/search/SearchBootstrap'
], function(angular, AppController, SearchBootstrap) {
    function init() {
        var App = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
        AppController.start(App);
        SearchBootstrap.start(App);
        // need to bootstrap angular since we wait for dojo/DOM to load
        angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
        return App;
    }
    return { start: init };
});
```

Hope that helps a bit.